# How to remove a forked project from my Github profile

Tags: git, github, git-fork

Accidentally I clicked on fork button on a github project. However, I dont want to show the project on my github profile.

How can I get remove the publicly forked project in GitHub?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A fork is a new repo in your account.

You can simply delete the repository: see "[Deleting a repository](https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repository)"

[image: https://github-images.s3.amazonaws.com/help/repository/repo-delete.png]

Comment: Thank you. I thought, Settings option is available in the page, where all repositories are listed. Now, I checked the repository page itself, and able to locate Settings link and can see the DangerZone.